# Django model - how to define foreign key refer to another table?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm working with a legay database so I have to set managed = False, which means I cannot update the database schema.

What I'm trying to do is select branches based on project id. Ideally in branches table it should have a project_id as foreign key but the previous system design is another table (branches_projects) stores this relationship.

I have been able to get around some problems using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw. raw() would return an RawQuerySet, which is not ideal.

I wonder if there's a way for me to define a foreign key in my branches table, which is the project_id, but refer/link that to the branches_projects table?

```
class Branches(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    branchpoint_str = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dev_lead_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    approved = models.IntegerField()
    for_customer = models.IntegerField()
    deactivated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    codb_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pm_lead_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    path_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    branchpoint_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    branchpoint_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'branches'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Branches'

class Projects(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        platform = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        enabled = models.IntegerField()
        path = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
        tag_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        codb_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        template = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
        image_path = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
        repository_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        number_scheme = models.CharField(max_length=32)
        special_dir = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
        project_family_id = models.IntegerField()
        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'projects'
            verbose_name_plural = 'projects'

class BranchesProjects(models.Model):
    # project_id = models.IntegerField()
    # branch_id = models.IntegerField()
    project = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branches, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'branches_projects'
```

My current raw query is like this

```
SELECT br.id, br.name, br.created_at, br.updated_at,
br.branchpoint_str, br.source
FROM branches as br
LEFT JOIN branches_projects as bp
ON br.id = bp.branch_id 
WHERE bp.project_id = %s AND source != 'other'
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got it working......

In the model, I use the manytomany as following:

```
class Branches(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
project = models.ManyToManyField(Projects,
    through='BranchesProjects',
    related_name='project')
branchpoint_str = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Then to get the same result as my raw sql, i do the following:

```
def get_sb(project_id):
    result = Branches.objects.filter(
        project=Projects.objects.get(id=project_id).id,
        ).exclude(source='other').order_by('-updated_at')
    print result.query
    return result
```